# How to get Request body{object} in prehandler in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-security, handler

How to get request body {object} in prehandler in spring boot?

I tried using by the following approaches:

1. `. byte[] bb = request.getInputStream().getBytes();
   log.info(new String(bb));`

but it is giving missing request body .

2. `String response = IOutil.toString(request.getINputStream());`

getting missing request body .

I want to handle **hpp** (http parameter pollution in my spring application.)

please help me out

Comment: Ask a question  about the problem you are trying to solve - preventing  hpp- rather than your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use BufferedReader in 1 case.